# using parseFloat returns user input as strings added together in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a budget calculator and the issue that I'm having is parsing the user input. For testing purposes, I was using parseInt() and that would add the totals just fine, but changing to parseFloat() autopopulates the "total" form with the user input added together as strings. The commented out line in the if-statement for `isNaN` is what I had tried before, and both simply return LiquidTotal as strings added all together.

What I want is to allow multiple numeric user inputs, such as 10 and 10.50, and for the total to display as `$20.50`, but right now it displays as `$1010.50`

```
var LiquidTotal;

function LiquidMath()
        {
            var a = document.getElementById("cash").value;
            var b = document.getElementById("checkings").value;
            var c = document.getElementById("savings").value;
            var d = document.getElementById("market").value;
            var e = document.getElementById("LCD").value;
            var f = document.getElementById("LiquidOther1").value;
            var g = document.getElementById("LiquidOther2").value;
            var h = document.getElementById("LiquidOther3").value;

            parseFloat(a).toFixed(2);
            parseFloat(b).toFixed(2);
            parseFloat(c).toFixed(2);
            parseFloat(d).toFixed(2);
            parseFloat(e).toFixed(2);
            parseFloat(f).toFixed(2);
            parseFloat(g).toFixed(2);
            parseFloat(h).toFixed(2);

            LiquidTotal = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h;

            if (isNaN(LiquidTotal))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                //document.getElementById("DisplayLiquidTotal").value = LiquidTotal;
                document.getElementById("DisplayLiquidTotal").value = '$' + parseFloat(LiquidTotal).toFixed(2);
            }

            return document.getElementById("LiquidTotal").value;
        }
```

Here is my HTML for this field, in case I messed anything up there as well.

```
<h4>Liquid Assets</h4>
   <div class="row" style="padding:1px;">
      <div class="col-xs-8">Cash On Hand: <input type="text" id="cash" onblur="LiquidMath()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;"/></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">Checking Account: <input type="text" id="checkings" onblur="LiquidMath()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;"/></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">Savings Account: <input type="text" id="savings" onblur="LiquidMath()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;"/></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">Money Market Fund: <input type="text" id="market" onblur="LiquidMath()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;"/></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">CD Less Than One Year: <input type="text" id="LCD" onblur="LiquidMath()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;"/></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">Other: <input type="number" id="LiquidOther1" onblur="LiquidMath()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;"/></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">Other: <input type="number" id="LiquidOther2" onblur="LiquidMath()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;"/></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">Other: <input type="number" id="LiquidOther3" onblur="LiquidMath()" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;"/></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">Total: <input type="text" id="DisplayLiquidTotal" onblur="LiquidMath()" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;"/></div>
```

Comment: Drop all conversions (`parseFloat(a).toFixed(2);`) and do `var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cash").value);` ... and the `.toFixed(2)` will format it all at output

Comment: That was how I originally did it, but when I did it that way I got a null return. I know what I've shown above is way longer and uglier, but for whatever reason, doing it all in one go didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems.

1. parseFloat and toFixed both return new values, they don't mutate the inputs.
2. While parseFloat returns a float, toFixed converts number types and returns a string.  So you'll still have a string if you keep toFixed.

Strings are not added with arithmetic, adding strings in Javascript results in concatenation.

If you want to add numbers together, you need to assign the return value of parseFloat and stop using toFixed.

Comment: This is what really fixed it to return the right value, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that parseFloat returns a value. It doesn't alter a value in place.

This is what you want:

```
a = parseFloat(a).toFixed(2);
b = parseFloat(b).toFixed(2);
```

... and so on.

Comment: The real problem with this is parseFloat converts to a number but toFixed converts it right back to a string, leaving you with the same error, but only 2 decimal places in each variable.

Comment: This on its own didn't fix the problem, but the other solution offered by Devon did not work without this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental issue lies, as mentioned by other answers, in parseFloat not altering the variable that it is passed.

It seems to me as though you are also being overzealous with rounding decimal places when I presume you only really need to do that right at the end when you want to display the result of the sum. I'd also suggest tidying things up by encapsulating the repeated behaviour into helper functions, so something like:

```
// Get an element by ID and convert it to a float
const getFloatById = element => {
  return parseFloat(document.getElementById(element));
}

const elementsToSum = ['cash', 'checkings', 'savings', 'market', 'LCD', 'LiquidOther1', 'LiquidOther2', 'LiquidOther3'];

// Iterate over the list of element names
LiquidTotal = elementsToSum.map(el => getFloatById(el))
  // use reduce to sum all elements
  .reduce((accum, current) => {
    return accum + current
  }, 0)
  // then convert to a 2 decimal place string
  .toFixed(2);
```